# Weblogic 10.3.4 & Spring 3.0.6 & web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic11g, weblogic-integration

currently working on developing a rest service that needs to be deployed on Weblogic 10.3.4. Using Spring 3.0.6 examples online but the basic loading of the DispatcherServlet seems to be causing problems with Weblogic.

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The exception shown in the weblogic console window was:

```
<07-Nov-2011 20:29:33 o'clock GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: unimplemented bytecode ================

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x026b26d0, pid=7200, tid=7924
#
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b51
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# j  javax.validation.Validation.byDefaultProvider()Ljavax/validation/bootstrap/GenericBootstrap;+0
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\bea\user_projects\domains\saw_ca_wl10\hs_err_pid7200.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The exception shown in the target AdminServer log was

```
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:54 o'clock GMT> <Info> <EJB> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697794074> <BEA-010008> <EJB Deploying file: KCS-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:54 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697794499> <BEA-149060> <Module KCS-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar of application KCS-ear-0 successfully transitioned from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:54 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697794499> <BEA-149059> <Module /KCS-webApp of application KCS-ear-0 is transitioning from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:55 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697795146> <BEA-149060> <Module /KCS-webApp of application KCS-ear-0 successfully transitioned from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:55 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697795270> <BEA-149059> <Module KCS-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar of application KCS-ear-0 is transitioning from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:55 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697795301> <BEA-149060> <Module KCS-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar of application KCS-ear-0 successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:55 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697795301> <BEA-149059> <Module /KCS-webApp of application KCS-ear-0 is transitioning from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:55 o'clock GMT> <Info> <Deployer> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1320697795302> <BEA-149060> <Module /KCS-webApp of application KCS-ear-0 successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server AdminServer.> 
####<07-Nov-2011 20:29:55 o'clock GMT> <Info> <ServletContext-/KCS-webApp> <JGOGGINS212> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1320697795498> <BEA-000000> <Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'>
```

Building using Maven and have all the spring-core/web/webmvc/context all defined as runtime dependent.

Also tried to copy the "org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE,jar" file to the bea\modules folder in an attempt to resolve runtime issues within weblogic.

Tried the weblogic-application.xml,

```
<prefer-application-packages>
<package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
<package-name>org.springframework.web.*</package-name>
<package-name>org.springframework.web.servlet.*</package-name>  
<prefer-application-packages>
```

All that, same problem.

I noted that the release notes have stated that "This version of WebLogic Server supports Spring 3.0.", http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13852/toc.htm#BGGEAIJJ

Comment: That's odd; I'm not sure what we did differently, but we're not seeing that, and it's strange that you'd get that particular error. What happens if you build it locally and deploy that?

Comment: Hi Dave, same issue. Do you have any of the libraries in your domain lib folder ? eg: <DIR>\bea\user_projects\domains\<my domain>\lib. I copied the org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar file here and it resolved an issue - gave me another though.

Comment: No, I put each app's libraries in that app's `WEB-INF/lib` to avoid versioning issues. The problem may be in a supporting lib, then; is there any other info available if you crank up the log level to DEBUG?

Comment: Referenced http://eclipsejpa.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-305-on-weblogic-10330.html, added all the jar mentioned to the \domains\<my domain>\lib folder and successfully deployed. However, I'm not able to view my index.jsp file as expected on welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Function code is limited by the size 64 KB in both version of Java 7 and  8. When our code exceeds more than 64 KB in function Compiler failed to compile the whole code and throws error as **Unimplemented Byte Code**

COMPILE ERROR:

ERROR MESSAGES/STACK TRACES THAT OCCUR :
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: unimplemented bytecode ================
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

**Note:**  Here function is consider as

1)Function is normal function one we write in jsp or java file.

2)Our normal jsp(Java Server Page) page is also treated as function when it is complied in java programming

Example:

```
// The Function Size Should Less Than 64KB
public static function myFunction(){
   // Your Code
}
```